# Azure Container Apps Dapr

Tags: azure

Good morning ,
I work on container applications,
I managed to create my container with Terraform but I am now stuck on Dapr I cannot install it,
When I do dapr -v I have nothing at execution level
Thank you in advance for your answers

create microservices with container applications

Comment: Check if this is helpful - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/microservices-dapr?tabs=bash%2Cazure-cli
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/dapr-overview?tabs=bicep1%2Cyaml

Answer (score 0):

In order to install dapr on your cluster

Follow the below steps-
Here I am using helm charts instead of dapr CLI and I will be installing version 1.12.

```
helm repo add dapr https://dapr.github.io/helm-charts/
helm repo update
```

Once the repo is downloaded, verify the available version using

```
helm search repo dapr --devel --versions
```

[image]

Install dapr with your preferred version.

```
helm upgrade --install dapr dapr/dapr --version=1.12 --namespace dapr-system --create-namespace --set global.ha.enable=true --wait
```

Now if you check, dapr is installed
[image]

and pods are active
[image]

Reference documents-
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/microservices-dapr?tabs=bash,azure-cli)
[Dapr Doc](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/hosting/kubernetes/kubernetes-deploy/)